# drag drop file upload with file api server side code

Tags: php, html, file-upload, fileapi

I am trying to make drag drop file upload using FILE api and folowing this tutorial

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications

its works fine. when i see ajax request "POST" data with firebug i see something like this

```
--30000 Content-Disposition: form-data; name='fileId'; filename='header.jpg' Content-Type: application/octet-stream Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã �JFIF��H�H��Ã¿Ã›�C�    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342Ã¿Ã›�C
```

How can i save this data in a image format at server end ??

You can check live demo @ http://www.amitpatil.me//demos/in_progress/gmail_fupload/file.html

Comment: Why not use this one? It works like a charm and is easy to setup. Any special requirement to implement your own upload functionality? http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: Actually i want to learn it myself so i want to find how things work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the global $_FILES. It contains all the information about the uploaded Data.
Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php.
In your case you will get the tmp. uploaded-file by using $_FILES['fieldID']['tmp_name'].

Comment: Its not normal file upload so it has nothing to do with $_FILES....i am using javascript reader object to send the file to the server.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but the data looks like normal fileuploaddata.